# Unable to run nodejs project - npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

Tags: node.js, git, npm, node-gyp

I'm new on nodeJS, so this may be a silly question.

I've just installed nodejs, node-gyp, npm, git, Python and MS Visual Studio C++ Express.

When I execute `"npm install"` I get the following output:

```
npm WARN package.json strider@1.6.6 No license field.

> contextify@0.1.14 install C:\Users\W7\Documents\GitHub\strider\node_modules\angular\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\W7\Documents\GitHub\strider\node_modules\angular\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(42,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install Visual Studio 2010 to build using the Visual Studio 2010 build tools. [C:\Users\W7\Documents\GitHub\strider\node_modules\angular\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\build\contextify.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\W7\Documents\GitHub\strider\node_modules\angular\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: n@1.3.0
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\W7\Documents\GitHub\strider\npm-debug.log
```

I'm probably missing something, does anyone know how to fix this?

I'm using Windows 7 64.

Comment: Have you tried an npm update before your install?

Answer (score 0):

Change your package or your OS,this OS doesn't support this package.

Comment: Can you provide more details about this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install `n` package under Windows. On their github page (https://github.com/tj/n) it is stated, that it does not work natively on windows

> (Note: `n` is not supported natively on Windows.)

You can try [`nvm-windows`](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) package, but i have never used it.

Alternatively, you can set-up [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) on your machine. I use it daily and can recommend it.

EDIT: I've just read you are running Windows 7, and WSL only works on Windows 10. I suggest upgrading.